# Airflow: How to start operators in parallel after first operator has finished

Tags: airflow

Currently i have a DAG consisting of 4 operators as shown below:

```
with DAG('dag', default_args=args, schedule_interval=schedule_interval, catchup=True) as dag:
main_dag = PythonOperator(
    task_id='1',
    python_callable=func,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

run_after_main_dag_1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='1',
    python_callable=foo,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

run_after_main_dag_2 = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='2',
    python_callable=foo,
    provide_context=True)

run_after_main_dag_2_2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='3',
    python_callable=foo,
    provide_context=False,
    dag=dag)

#this runs sequential, but shouldn't.
main_dag >> run_after_main_dag_1 >> run_after_main_dag_2 >> run_after_main_dag_2_2
```

Here's what i'd like to achieve:

1. Run `main_dag` operator
2. Once `main_dag` is finished, start `run_after_main_dag_1` and `run_after_main_dag_2` in parallel, as they are not independent of each other.

I simply can't find how to achieve this in the docs anywhere. There must be a simple syntax i have completely overlooked.

Anyone who knows how to make it happen?

Comment: > they are _not_ independent of each other, or are they?

Answer (score 1):

So there was a simple answer:

```
main_dag >> run_after_main_dag_1
main_dag >> run_after_main_dag_2 >> run_after_main_dag_2_2
```

Answer (score 0):

In Airflow `>>` and `<<` are used to set up the downstream and upstream dependency.

You code

```
main_dag >> run_after_main_dag_1 >> run_after_main_dag_2 >> run_after_main_dag_2_2 #sequentially
```

It is actually defining the relationship that runs sequentially as `run_after_main_dag_1`'s upstream is set to `main_dag` and so on.

In order to separate `run_after_main_dag_1` and `run_after_main_dag_2` you can define relationship such that both have upstream task as `main_dag`

```
main_dag >> run_after_main_dag_1 # It is just dependent on main_dag
main_dag >> run_after_main_dag_2 # It is just dependent on main_dag
```

It will then kick off the two tasks in parallel once the main_dag task finish its execution